# Is this a vector space? $\{f(x) \in C[-1,1]: f(1) = 1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is this a vector space?
$$\{f(x) \in C[-1,1]: f(1) = 1\}$$

answer says, any subset of a vector space is a vector space, which contains $0$. So $f(1)$ is such a vector space, and thus we must have $f(1) = 0$ instead of $1$.

I am thinking, if this is true, then $f(x)$ has to be $0$ for all $x$, right?

Comment: The zero function is the zero vector- is that what you are asking?

Comment: My question is the first line of the text. Is this a vector space

Comment: No- this isn't a vector space.

Comment: why not? why must f(1) be 0?

Comment: Please see my answer :). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One of the axioms of a vector space is the existence of a $0$ vector.

Now for the space of functions, $C[-1,1]$, the zero vector is the $0$ function, i.e. the function $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

But your subset does not contain this function, and hence doesn't contain the $0$ vector, and hence your set isn't a vector subspace.

Comment: helps a lot. Thanks!